# Python equivalent of R's c()?

Tags: python

This question has already been asked here: [Python equivalent of R c() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443778/python-equivalent-of-r-c-function), but unfortunately the solution given doesn't exactly apply to me.

For instance, if I combine values, into a vector or list, in R like so:

```
x = c(2,3,6,8)
```

I can preform calculations on that list, for example:

```
x*2
Output:
4 6 12 16
```

However, I'm not sure how to achieve the same thing in Python. The previously asked question (in the link above) deals with a list of numbers in a particular range. for example,

```
x = list(range(1:10))
```

I am wondering, how do I define a list of numbers (not in a range) in Python?

Comment: If you're using `numpy`, then you just do `x = np.array([2, 3, 6, 8])` then `x * 2` ? eg - you actually give it a `list` of numbers...

Comment: (1) That does define a list -- it just creates it from a range; (2) if you want elementwise operations on vectors/matrices/n-dim arrays, use `numpy`.

Comment: `np.array`  did the job for me. Thanks for your help

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443778/python-equivalent-of-r-c-function

Answer (score -2):

in python, you could use numpy arrays to do such things

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([2, 3, 7])
y = x*2
```

and y will be equal to numpy.array([4, 6, 14])

Comment: I'm afraid not, that would produce: `[2, 3, 7, 2, 3, 7]`

Comment: Python does that for a different purpose.

Comment: Thats my bad, I was thinking of numpy arrays, which should have just been my original answer...